# Monitoring Windows machines from Linux with winrm / CIM / WMI using active directory accounts

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, monitoring, kerberos

It's all in the title :)

I have to monitor windows clients/servers.

Currently I use relay windows servers to monitor the remote clients with powershell scripts.
I wish to change that and to use linux Redhat 9 to monitor the windows.

We have a technical account in the AD that is in the local administrator groups on each remote host that we use to authenticate on the windows for powershell sessions.

There's powershell on linux and somehow that would be cool to be able to use it,
As we use an AD account I think there's a kerberos thingie we have to configure, and hopefully not so much on the DC ( as it is another team that configure them )

Googling on the subject don't bring much result on the course of action to make it work..
Basically we want to interrogate wirm / WMI / CIM remotely from linux to windows.

Thanks for your inputs !

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.